# Replace HTTP with HTTPS on var siteurl to remove the xmlhttprequest error

Tags: javascript, https, xmlhttprequest, typo3, mixed-content

I have this error :

```
Mixed content the page at was loaded over https but requested an insecure xmlhttprequest endpoint
```

When checked to source code i find this javascript :

**HTML OUTPUT :**

```
    var checkTasksInterval=10000;
    var taskesstr='111';
    var thispageid=1;
    var siteurl='http://www.example.com/';
```

How can I change the `var siteurl` to `https` in this javascript ?

```
    <script language="JavaScript">
    var checkTasksInterval='.$sysconf['checkTasksInterval'].';
    var tasksstr=\''.$tasksstr.'\';
    var thispageid='.$GLOBALS['TSFE']->id.';
    var siteurl=\''.\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::getIndpEnv('TYPO3_SITE_URL').'\';
    </script>
```

Comment: var siteurl='https://www.example.com/';

Comment: I replaced `var siteurl=\''.\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::getIndpEnv('TYPO3_SITE_URL').'\';` with `var siteurl='example.com';` but I get error on the output page

Comment: Why not enforcing https for the whole site, e.g. with a mod_rewrite rule in your .htaccess? Or you could try to set  `var siteurl='https://www.example.tld';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the ajax `siteurl` call :

I changed this :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: siteurl+surl,
```

to :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'https://example.com/index.php?eID=tasksdata',
```